# How does the google search 'verbatim' option work?

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing

I know what it does (finding original content), but what I wish to know is if two pages are the same how is determined what is the original one ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how Google works but not about running your own website.

Answer (score 2):

> finding original content

"Verbatim" search has little to do with "finding original content". In fact, *Verbatim search* is just like an ordinary Google search except that Google will *tend to* use the exact keywords/phrases that you actually search for (as per the English definition of *Verbatim*, "in exactly the same words as were used originally"), rather than using it's heuristics engine to search for what it thinks you wanted to search for (keyword variations, synonyms, etc.)

So, the *default* ordering of the search results is the same, "relevance" (as determined by Google's internal - closely guarded, top secret - algorithms). This is regardless of whether you are using "Verbatim" search or not.